# How to define TypeScript types when used with React useState and the previous state inside a state updating function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-state, react-typescript

I am pretty new to development and need some help—and patience. I'm converting a React project to TypeScript and having some issues managing and updating the state inside my Context component.

I'm building a log viewer that displays a series of tasks and their nested sub-tasks, depending on which task is selected.

The events are defined in an Event class which is populated with data from a custom useFetch hook. These are stored as objects inside Event arrays. When a task is selected, it is stored in a currently 'selectedTask' state and must also be pushed into a 'Hierarchy' array.

The idea is to display a hierarchy of subsequently selected tasks, as the user clicks through multiple nested layers of task logs.

These events are defined inside a type 'ContextObject' as follows:

```
    hierarchy: Event[] | undefined
    setHierarchy: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Event[] | undefined>>
    selectedSubEvent: Event[];
    setSelectedSubEvent: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Event[]>>;
```

They are managed via useState:

```
    const [hierarchy, setHierarchy] = useState<Event[] | undefined>([]);
    const [selectedSubEvent, setSelectedSubEvent] = useState<Event[]>([]);
```

In order to update the hierarchy with the selected task, I'm using a state updating function inside a useEffect as follows, and getting an error on the '...prevState':

```
    useEffect(() => { 
        setHierarchy((prevState) => [...prevState, selectedSubEvent])
    }, [selectedSubEvent]);
```

The error I'm getting:

```
    Type 'Event[] | undefined' is not an array type.ts(2461)
    (parameter) prevState: Event[] | undefined
```

When I forgo the state update function inside the useEffect and just set 'Hierarchy' to the 'selectedEvent', it does set that single event to the hierarchy, but obviously I need more than that.

I've also tried checking the prevState before spreading it, but that gave multiple errors:

```
    setHierarchy((prevState) =>
        prevState ? [...prevState, selectedSubEvent] : [selectedSubEvent]
        );

//Errors
Argument of type '(prevState: Event[] | undefined) => (Event | Event[])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Event[] | undefined>'.
  Type '(prevState: Event[] | undefined) => (Event | Event[])[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: Event[] | undefined) => Event[] | undefined'.
    Type '(Event | Event[])[]' is not assignable to type 'Event[]'.
      Type 'Event | Event[]' is not assignable to type 'Event'.
        Type 'Event[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Event': key, id, startTime, endTime, and 3 more.ts(2345)
```

I realise I'm not providing much in the way of what I've tried, but I have tried countless articles, tutorials and both the React and TypeScript documentation and I'm at a loss ‍♂️

Please let me know if I can provide any more info. I'm happy to keep digging if someone can just point me in the right direction.

---

## UPDATE

I tried the suggestions offered by @Leigh.D and got the following results.

FIRST:
Removing 'undefined' gives me the following errors:

```
Argument of type '(prevState: Event[]) => (Event | Event[])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Event[]>'.
  Type '(prevState: Event[]) => (Event | Event[])[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: Event[]) => Event[]'.
    Type '(Event | Event[])[]' is not assignable to type 'Event[]'.
      Type 'Event | Event[]' is not assignable to type 'Event'.
        Type 'Event[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Event': key, id, startTime, endTime, and 3 more.ts(2345)
(parameter) prevState: Event[]
```

SECOND:
This also results in an error on the setHierarchy property in my context provider value, but when I remove 'undefined' from setHierarchy in the context object like so:

```
setHierarchy: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Event[]>>
```

this error goes away:

```
Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<Event[]>>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<Event[] | undefined>>'.
  Type 'SetStateAction<Event[] | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<Event[]>'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<Event[]>'.ts(2322)
sub-event-context.tsx(20, 2): The expected type comes from property 'setHierarchy' which is declared here on type 'SubEventContextObject'
(property) setHierarchy: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Event[] | undefined>>
```

THIRD:
When I combine removing the 'undefined' as per FIRST and check the 'prevState' I get the following:

```
Argument of type '(prevState: Event[]) => (Event | Event[])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Event[]>'.
  Type '(prevState: Event[]) => (Event | Event[])[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: Event[]) => Event[]'.
    Type '(Event | Event[])[]' is not assignable to type 'Event[]'.
      Type 'Event | Event[]' is not assignable to type 'Event'.
        Type 'Event[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Event': key, id, startTime, endTime, and 3 more.ts(2345)
(parameter) prevState: Event[]
```

FOURTH:
When I remove the checked 'prevState' and typecast it, VSCode/Prettier wraps it in parenthesis—I don't know if this is normal behaviour?

```
useEffect(() => {
        setHierarchy((prevState) => [
            ...(prevState as Event[]),
            selectedSubEvent,
        ]);
    }, [selectedSubEvent]);
```

That aside, I get the same errors as in THIRD.

## SOLUTION

Thank you to Leigh.D and Daniel Baldi for helping me resolve this. It appears I had TWO problems and their two answers collectively fixed my errors. Anyone reading this looking to resolve similar issues, be sure to read BOTH answers.

I'm marking Daniel's solution as the accepted answer, primarily because in my inexperienced opinion, it was the more complicated issue. Please correct me if my thinking is incorrect.

Thank you again for the help offered. I do appreciate it!

Deon

Comment: Can you provide further information on the multiple errors that you're getting when checking `prevState`? It looks fine to me

Comment: With a state declaration like `const [hierarchy, setHierarchy] = useState<Event[] | undefined>([]);` if you never do something like `setHierarchy(undefined)` is it ever possible for `hierarchy` to be undefined? In other words, would `const [hierarchy, setHierarchy] = useState<Event[]>([]);` help resolve the typescript discrepancy?

Comment: @DanielBaldi Thank you for having a look! I've updated the original question with the errors.

Comment: @DrewReese I never replied to you Drew, but after following Leigh.D's advice, that does indeed appear to have mostly resolved the issue. As stated in my reply to Daniel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70201279/13339799) I needed to add a 'return' as well.
Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think I've figured out what's happening here. Let us consider what is going on here first:

```
setHierarchy((prevState) =>
    prevState ? [...prevState, selectedSubEvent] : [selectedSubEvent]
    );
```

As you've stated in your `ContextObject` interface, `selectedSubEvent` is an array of `Event` and `prevState` has the same type of `hierarchy` and thus is an array of `Event` or undefined.

So looking at the code, if `prevState` evaluates to a *truthy* value, you're creating this `[...prevState, selectedSubEvent]`, which contains a spread of `prevState`, which results in `Event`, and `selectedSubEvent`, which results in an **array of Event**. This is the first problem, as the resulting value ends up being of type `(Event | Event[])[]` when it should be of type `Event[]`.

When `prevState` is *falsy*, you're setting `hierarchy` to be `[selectedSubEvent]`. This creates an **array of arrays** of Event (`Event[][]`). That's problem number two!

I might have gotten something wrong here as it is pretty tricky to try and write code without actually running it, but my guess is try this and it should be working fine:

```
setHierarchy((prevState) =>
    prevState ? [...prevState, ...selectedSubEvent] : selectedSubEvent
    );
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel! That solved the error. I appreciate the clear explanation.

I don't want you to think I wasted your time, but literally while you were posting this I was trying various things and discovered that if I added a 'return' to 'setHierarchy' **without** the check, the error also went away: `setHierarchy((prevState) => { return [...prevState, ...selectedSubEvent]  });`
What would be considered best practice? With or without the 'prevState' check?

Comment: Actually scrap that, it was not the 'return' that did it, but rather adding the spread operator before '...selectedSubEvent' ‍♂️

Comment: Yes, I figured :) As I stated in my answer, spreading `selectedSubEvent` is the way to fix it. Explicitly returning the value does not have any impact on TS's type evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your type definition (specifically undefined) and how the spread operator interprets it.

```js
const [hierarchy, setHierarchy] = useState<Event[] | undefined>([]);
```

You can either remove undefined from the type (since you default the state to an empty array anyway), perform a check when setting state or typecast prevState so the spread operator knows its an array (not best option) ie:

```js
setHierarchy((prevState) => prevState? [...prevState, selectedSubEvent] : [selectedSubEvent])

setHierarchy((prevState) => [...prevState as Event[], selectedSubEvent])
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to assist!
I will update the original question with what I got after trying your suggestions.

Comment: To add to this, I've discovered that adding a spread operator to the '...selectedSubEvent' in 'setHierarchy' has resolved all issues mentioned in my update. In terms of best practice, is it better with or without the 'prevState' check?